# Laplace equation in a domain with holes

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, harmonic-functions

Suppose $u_r(x_1,x_2)$ in $B_1(0) \setminus B_r(0)$ satisfy 
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\Delta u_r &=0\\
u_r(|x|=r)&=-\log r \\
u_r(|x|=1)&=0 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
with $0<r<1$.

Then one can show that $u_r=\log (1/|x|)$ converges to $u^*=\log (1/|x|)$, as $r$ goes to $0$, in $B_1(0) \setminus \{0\}$.

But if we have finitely many holes and consider the domain $B_1(0) \setminus \bigcup B_{r_i}(x_i)$

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\Delta u_r &=0 \quad\text{ in } B_1(0) \setminus \bigcup B_{r_i}(x_i)\\
u_r(|x-x_i|=r_i)&=-\log r_i \\
u_r(|x|=1)&=0 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
with all $\overline{B_{r_i}(x_i)} \subset B_1(0)$,
how to show that the solution still converges and is locally bounded in $B_1(0)\setminus \{\bigcup x_i\}$, as all $r_i$ go to 0 ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $v$ be the solution of
$$
\left\{ \enspace
\begin{aligned}
  &\Delta v =0 && \text{in $B_1(0)$,} \\
  &v = -\,\sum\nolimits_i \log (1/|x-x_i|) && \text{on $\partial B_1(0)$.}
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Then $u_r$ converges locally uniformly in $\overline B_1(0)\setminus
\bigcup_i\{x_i\}$ as $r=\{r_i\}\to 0$ to
$$
u = v + \sum\nolimits_i \log (1/|x-x_i|).
$$
Indeed, $u(x) = \log (1/|x-x_j|) + O(1)$ as $x\to x_j$ for all $j$. Therefore, $(u-u_r)\bigr|_{\,K}=O(1)$ as $r\to0$ for any compact $K\subset \overline B_1(0)\setminus \bigcup_i\{x_i\}$. Now, if $u_r \to \tilde u$ locally uniformly in $\overline B_1(0)\setminus \bigcup_i\{x_i\}$ as $r\to0$ along a subsequence, $u-\tilde u$ is harmonic in $B_1(0)$ (the singularities at the $x_i$ are removable) and vanishes on $\partial B_1(0)$. Hence, $u\equiv\tilde u$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can i conclude that $u(|x-x_i|=r_i)=-\log r_i$ from your construction?

Comment: One has $u(x) = -\log r_j + C_j + O(r_j)$ for $|x-x_j|=r_j$ as
$r_j\to 0$, where $C_j= v(x_j) - \sum_{i\neq j}\log |x_i-x_j|$. In general, $C_j\neq0$.